# Does 'Front End Developer' or 'Marketing Developer' come under "Developer Programmer" category in skilled worker occupation?

Tags: immigration, australia, pakistani-citizen

I am working as a Front End Developer at a Canadian company from Pakistan. They are registered in Pakistan too. I want to move to Australia and I found that for skilled worker immigration, the worker class that I can come under is "Developer Programmer." I want to verify does "Front End Developer" come under this category?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The final determination will be made by Immigration, but **yes**,  that should qualify.

Note that you may also need to have a skills assessment done to confirm that you do indeed have the skills and experience needed for the role

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, I have applied for `Developer Programmer (261312)` specialisation and it basically is catch all... I have worked variety of areas (frontend, backend, databases you name it...) and have reference got accepted or rejected was based on 'correct' reference format, and not on the title...

When providing references you need to follow specific standard of letter, below are 2 examples one that got rejected other accepted...

**Successful:**
[image]

**Failed:**
[image]

I suggest you make forms for each company that look like former example, then get originals to Australian embassy for notarization (17GBP per page) and you should be solid...